# Vectors & Ifelse Logic - Won't Populate Vector

Tags: r, if-statement, vector, logic, conditional-statements

I'm creating a function that takes two inputs: delta, and length. The function modifies an existing vector - let's call this vector base - by delta for 'length' specified elements.

I need to create a new vector, let's call it 'adjusted'. This vector, adjusted, needs to populate based on one condition: If the index value for the base vector is less than the length parameter specified in the function input, then I want to increase the base vector by delta for all elements less than length. All elements in the base vector greater than the specified length parameter are to remain the same as in base vector.

Here is an example of my code: I have tried to implement the logic in two ways.
1. Using an ifelse because it allows for vectorized output. 
2. Using an if else logic.

```
    adjusted <- vector() #initialize the vector.

#Create a function. 
Adjustment <- function(delta, length) {

  ifelse((index < length), (adjusted <- base + delta), (adjusted <- base)) 

  head(adjusted)
}

    #Method 2. 
   Adjustment <- function(delta, length) {

      if (index < length) {
            adjusted <- base + delta
        }
      else {adjusted <- base}

      head(adjusted)
    }
```

Where I am experiencing trouble is with my newly created vector, adjusted, will not populate. I'm not quite sure what is happening - I am very new to R and any insight would be much appreciated.

EDIT: With some advice given, I was able to return output. The only issue is that the 'adjusted' vector is now 2x the length of the index vector. I see that this is happening because there are two calculations, one in the if value is true, and one in the if value is false. However, I want the function to write to the vector adjusted only in the elements for which the index is less than the parameter length.

For example. Let's say that the index vector is 10. If I set length to 3, I want adjusted to reflect a change for elements 1:3 and the same information in base for 4:10.

My code reflects adjusted is now length 20. How can I approach this and maintain the original value of the vector?

```
adjusted <- c()

Adjustment <- function(delta, length) {
ifelse(index < length, adjusted <<- c(adjusted, base + delta), adjusted <<- c(adjusted, base))

  head(adjusted)
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you using `head`? With no second argument `head` returns the first 6 elements.

Comment: Just for self check. I wanted to return the first 5 observations of adjusted to see if the calculation was functioning properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a bit of Boolean algebra:

```
  adjusted <- base + delta*(base > length)
```

Comment: Would I implement this boolean algebra for both conditions? Do I place tihs inside the ifelse statement? I understand what is happening conceptually, however being new to R I have issues with implementation. Thanks

Comment: This is very concise and short answer. Perhaps OP wants `base + delta*(base > length)` to be `base + delta*(base <= length)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Adjustment <- function(delta, length) {

if (index < length) {
for(i in 1:length-1){
  adjusted[i] <- base[i] + delta
}
}
else {adjusted <- base}

head(adjusted)

}


index=2
length=5
base <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
delta = 2

Adjustment(delta,length)
```

This returns a vector that has all values < indexVALUE from base vector added by delta.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - base is a vector that already exists in my code.

Comment: It works, im not sure what problems your having. Make sure all of your variables are declared and global if your not gonna pass them to or declare them in function. Modifying global vars in a function is a bad idea

Comment: mind taking a look at the edit I posted in the original post? My issue is that the adjusted vector is double the length - I want the ifelse condition to NOT append the vector, but rather modify the elements that are less than the inputted length parameter. Thank you for your comments!